# NameError in function to retrieve JSON data

Tags: python, json

I'm using **python 3.6.1** and have the following code which successfully retrieves data in JSON format:

```
import urllib.request,json,pprint

url = "https://someurl"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
pprint.pprint(data)
```

I want to wrap this in a function, so i can reuse it. This is what i have tried in a file called getdata.py:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json


def get_json_data(url):
    response = urlopen(url)
    return json.loads(response.read())
```

and this is the error i get after importing the file and attempting to print out the response:

```
>>> import getdata
>>> print(getdata.get_json_data("https://someurl"))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Nick\getdata.py", line 6, in get_json_data
from urllib.request import urlopen
NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined
```

i also tried this and got the same error:

```
import urllib.request,json


def get_json_data(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return json.loads(response.read())
```

What do i need to do to get this to work please?

cheers

Comment: Strange. Your stack trace says the error is on line 6, but line 6 isn't `from urllib.request import urlopen`. Are you sure that's exactly the error message that appears?

Comment: @Kevin yes the error was on that line but i think the issue was with an atom package.See my answer below. cheers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem went away.

Comment: @martineau how is it off-topic?? :(

Comment: It says why right in the comment. What part of it didn't you understand?

Comment: @martineau i posted this because i thought the issue was my syntax, turned out it wasn't after more research on my part so i answered my own question. You think that deserved a downvote?!

Comment: Nick: You're assuming I'm the one who down-voted your question, which is incorrect. However if you don't stop arguing with me, I'm going to, too. Regardless, if it was a problem with your syntax, Python probably would have let you know and refused to run your script at all.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you, and your comment did start with "I'm voting to close this question.." so,  I guess I got that bit, right ? Good bye

Answer (score 0):

Its working now ! I think the problem was the hydrogen addon i have for the Atom editor. I uninstalled it, tried again and it worked. Thanks for looking.

Comment: In that case I suggest deleting your question. I doubt it has much value to anyone else.

Comment: Actually you're wrong.my colleague here has jupyter notebooks and the same atom setup. He got the same issue even with a newer version of python.took the same steps and it worked. So much for no value..